# code igniter zend barcode library not working

Tags: zend-framework, codeigniter-3

I'm using Zend Barcode library for my codeigniter project.
previously it work fine. but, now i'm getting blank image instead of barcode
how can i fix this issue?

**controller**

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Printing extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('zend');
    }

    public function bar_code()
    {
        $page  = 'barcode';
        $ch_id = $this->session->user['church_id'];

        $data['tbl_data'] = $this->print_model->members_barcode($ch_id);
        $data['off_type']     = $off_type;
        $data['church_name']  = $this->session->user['church_name'];
        $data['main_content'] = 'print/'.$page;
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }

    //Barcode Render
    public function barcode($data)
    {
        $this->zend->load('zend/barcode');
        Zend_Barcode::render(
            'code128', 
            'image', 
            array(
                'text' => $data, 
                'barHeight' => 35, 
                'drawText' => FALSE, 
                'withQuietZones' => FALSE,
                'barWidth' => 100, 
            ));
    }
}
```

**view**

```
<img class="br-img" src="<?php echo site_url('printing/barcode/'.$value->mem_tbl_id.$off_type); ?>" alt="">
```

**preview**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is generate file based data not path file information so you should change view to a link that generated file, because html  need path source